# jQuery selector to find link and all element inside

Tags: jquery, selector

I need to select any links within a div e.g. div abc --- to finally unbind its click event.

```
<div id=abc> 
<a href=google.com>first link</a> 
<a href=google.com><img> src=google.png/>second link</a> 
<a href=google.com><span>xxxxx</span> second link</a> 
</div>
```

I use below selector

```
$('#abc a')
```

but it only work if the hyperlink only has text inside (first example above) -- if i put span or image (second and third examples) -- i still can click the hyperlink. In other words, above jquery selector did not select its children.

What's the right jQuery in above?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What do you mean with *unbind its click event*? Are you binding a click handler before? Or do you just want to prevent the default behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('#abc a')` only selects `a` elements. If you want to select `a` elements *and* all descendants, this selector does the job, though it's not the most efficient:

```
$('#abc a, #abc a *')
```

If you don't mind doing it in two steps, you can make it a bit quicker:

```
var $links = $('#abc a');
$links.add($links.find('*'));
```